# Redirect grails default view to another view

Tags: grails, gsp

This is the URL Mapping class of grails.

When i call http:// localhost :8080/Pro i get directed to the `index.gsp` page. but i want it to be redirected to `Person/list`.

I have edited the `UrlMappings` class but i get a 404 instead.

```
HTTP Status 404 - /KickStartPro/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/Person/list.jsp
```

/

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(view:"/Person/list")
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a controller for Person? Even a scaffolded one? If so, then redirect to the controller method instead:

    "/" (controller:'person',action:'list')

Also, check your Grails application.properties. It looks like you have some conflict between what the app root is: 'Pro' vs 'KickStartPro'.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is hidden in your question: "but i want it to be redirected to Person/list". So rename you folder **/views/Person** -> **/view/person** (according grails convention), then add **PersonController**:

```
class PersonController {

    def list() {}
}
```

Then add **HomeController** with redirect to **PersonController**:

```
class HomeController {

    def index() {
        redirect(controller: 'person', action: 'list')
    }
}
```

And finally modify your **UrlMappings** to poin root url to **HomeController**:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(controller: "home")
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}
```

**Update**: pass all need data to list view. For example for **Person** list action may look like:

```
def list(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    [personInstanceList: Person.list(params), personInstanceTotal: Person.count()]
}
```

Comment: What is `HomeController` i cant find it ? i am a newbie

Comment: "Then add HomeController". You have to create it. Take a look here http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Command%20Line/create-controller.html or if you use IDEA create controller by right click on controller folder and select New->Grails controller

Comment: Yes i did that. i am getting this error - `Tag [paginate] is missing required attribute [total]`  Any idea how to solve it ?

Comment: See update. The problen you are not passing required values to gsp

Comment: why do you need a `HomeController`? You can point to `PersonController` directly

Comment: Because without redirect from home controller url will stay http://localhost:8080/Pro. Redirect provides a little bit clear solution

Comment: Still same error `Tag [paginate] is missing required attribute [total]`. Any clue

Comment: see updated version. And pass to page from controller total value variable with the same name as used on view